# How to host my ASP.NET Application on GoDaddy?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to upload my work to my site, but when I view the Default.aspx file in a web browser, I just see the code, not the actual "rendering" of the code. Any know know what I am doing wrong?

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Post the URL to your image (use imgur if you need a host)

Comment: Is your site hosted on Windows/IIS?

Comment: http://imgur.com/t17Ir60

Comment: I'm not sure what Windows/IIS is. It's hosted on a GoDaddy Server.

Comment: That URL contains an image of the site. Can't you post a URL to the actual site? And what is the raw content of this page?

Comment: If I had to guess, @jake, I'd say your GoDaddy server isn't a Windows server.  Do you know what type of hosting you have?

Comment: +1 to Doc for manually uploading the image for a new user :)

Answer (score 4):

You need hosting that supports ASP.Net, otherwise server simply will render page as text. There are plenty around - search and find one that fits your needs/budget.

Note that the same would happen with any other server side language if uploaded to host that does not support that particular language.

Comment: Side note: GoDaddy are horrible.

Comment: It says my server has advanced .Net language support. Here is a screen shot of my plan. http://imgur.com/DXXoRSZ

Comment: @SimonWhitehead why is it horrible and what would my other choices be?

Comment: Agree with @SimonWhitehead.  jake a quick google search will turn up lots of dirt on godaddy.  I'm principally against them.  For my hosting I use https://iwantmyname.com/ (no affiliation) -- at least they're transparent.

Comment: @jake that is not what your plan has. Your plan is Linux, and that note is saying use Windows for .Net. Switch it over to Windows. The only problem I've had with GoDaddy is that ridiculous fact that they still don't offer ASP.NET 4.5. So for one of my new sites I've had to switch hosts.